# Verilog task based TB issue

Tags: verilog

I am quite new to verilog, specially using it for TB coding and I am facing the following issue -

I am working on verifying round-robin (RR) arbiter and want to check the DUT grant with a TB modeled grant. I am writing a task to implement the TB model and then calling the task at every posedge of clock as follows -

```
  always @(posedge clk or posedge reset) begin 
  if(reset) reset_state;//task to reset state
  else begin
    //Initialising req vector every cycle
    req_vc = {req4, req3, req2, req1, req0};
    for (index=0; index<5; index=index+1) begin 
      temp[index] = rr_pri_state[index]; 
    end
    chk_grant; //task that gives out checker grant
    **if(gnt_id_checker != gnt_id)** begin//logic to compare checker grant with DUT grant (gnt_id) and end test if false 
    $display ("\tERROR!! Model grant and DUT grant IDs MISMATCH.\n\t\tModel grant = %d\n\t\tDUT grant = %d ", gnt_id_checker, gnt_id);
    #1 $finish;
    end
  end
 end
```

All my variables are globally defined

The issue is with the if comparison just after chk_grant task is called. When I simulate this I see that the values for gnt_id and gnt_id_checker used for comparison are not being updated to the latest one for that cycle. It is still performing comparison on old values. If i introduce #1 delay before if statement then everything works as expected with the correct values.

So I want to understand if this is expected or if I have approached this incorrectly?

Here is how my chk_grant task looks like for your reference. It basically finds out highest priority requestor and updated memory to reflect the new priority order

```
//task to calculate checker grant AND update priority state for next cycle
task chk_grant;
begin
i=0;
while (i<5) begin
  req_index = rr_pri_state[i]; 
  if(req_vc[req_index]) begin //we have found the req getting grant this cycle
    gnt_id_checker = req_index; 
    k = 5-(i+1); //i+1 req will have the highest priority next cycle
    for (j=0; j<k; j=j+1) begin
      rr_pri_state[j] = temp[i+j+1];
    end
    for (j=0; j<=i; j=j+1) begin
      rr_pri_state[j+k] = temp[j];
    end
    i=5; 
    end //end of if
  i=i+1;
  end //end of while loop
end
endtask
```

PS - I have no particular reason for using task here. If you think an event/function is better here please do let me know how and why so. Any other inputs for improving this would be much appreciated. Thanks!

Comment: From the point of view of a programming style, using an automatic function which returns the value and uses parameters with **no** global variables would be better. It would be easier to read and less prone to errors. There is nothing 'taskish' in your task, so a function would work. But even for tasks one should use params and 'automatic'.

Comment: @Serge - Thank you for your comments. I will read up about automatic tasks/functions. But I do not grasp what you imply by this - "There is nothing 'taskish' in your task..."

Comment: A `task` is there  to allow code which advances simulation time. I do see no such code  in your task, like `@` or `#` which wait for events or do delays. As such, it is identical to a function with no return.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not sure if theres anything wrong with the approach you are taking (ie, doing the work in a separate task, which in my mind makes more sense than a function as you are updating a few globals, not just getting the `gnt_id_checker`. If it was just getting a single value out, I would use a function).

The reason you need a `#1` is that when the design run, I assume `gnt_id` comes from a NBA (`<=`) from some register. Thus you are updating your `gnt_id_checker` in the current process right away (blocking assignment, `=`) but the assignment of `gnt_id` is delayed into the postponed region and thus not being used by the if-statement in performing the check. If it happens you are updating `gnt_id` combinationally, then theres a race condition between this block and that assigning `gnt_id`. Im assuming theres another block actually providing the stimulus to the design which is hard to tell without more information on your variables. If this same block is providing the stimulus, you definitely not giving your design a chance to run before checking the result (which it basically comes down to either way).

So to answer you directly, yes, this is expected and no, your general approach looks fine. Though for stylistic comments, I would suggest calling your checker a golden model as that is what you are doing. So, the task might be called `run_golden` instead (checkers are a thing in SystemVerilog as a separate concept). And would move `temp` into the task so the golden model is entirely contained within the task.

Comment: Thanks Unn. Your explanation makes sense. gnt_id is not coming from an NBA but from a combo logic but that would lead to a race condition as you said. So i basically need to give my design time to run before doing a comparison. I will happily stay with #1 delay for now that I understand